# Accessing an array chunk in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Hello I am having some trouble when it comes to iterating through my array chunks.

I am trying to put together an image gallery in which sets of 3 images follow a pattern then the next set of three follow the opposite of the pattern. I am pretty sure I am close, but I can not quite seem to figure out how exactly to select either the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. chunk of my array with a for loop.

This is a print_r of my sample set.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => images/uploads/cardinal.png [1] => images/uploads/fb.png [2] => images/uploads/logo.png ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => images/uploads/masc.png [1] => images/uploads/sportclubslogo.png [2] => images/uploads/venue.jpg )
)
```

I then have the two patterns which print out three images in a certain pattern, the problem is I am unsure how to loops through my chunks and select the evens to follow pattern1 and the odds to follow pattern2. Below is the code I am currently using to attempt this:

```
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    print_r($chunk);
    if($chunks % 2 == 0){
        echo "<div class='row'>
            <div class='gal-img medium-8 large-8 columns'>";
                echo "<img src='".$chunk[0]."' alt='gallery1'/>";
        echo "</div>
            <div class='gal-img medium-4 large-4 columns'>";
                echo "<img src='".$chunk[1]."' alt='gallery2'/>";
                echo "<img src='".$chunk[2]."' alt='gallery3'/>";
        echo "</div>
             </div>";
   }
   else {
       echo "<div class='row'>
           <div class='gal-img medium-4 large-4 columns'>";
               echo "<img src='".$chunk[0]."' alt='gallery4'/>";
               echo "<img src='".$chunk[1]."' alt='gallery5'/>";
       echo "</div>            
           <div class='gal-img medium-8 large-8 columns'>";
               echo "<img src='".$chunk[2]."' alt='gallery6'/>";
       echo "</div>
    </div>";
   }
}
```

I am still planning on refactoring the foreach loop, I just want to see it working before I write the two functions. The final output I am trying to achieve looks similar to this:

```
|       || small |
| Large || small |
| small ||       |
| small || Large |
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you were referring to `chunk[index]` as opposed to using `chunks[index]`

Comment: This was 100% a problem  with the images not showing up >.< I am going to put an edit in real fast; however, now the images only show up thru the else statement. The first array chunk should follow the if and the second the else, so on and so forth.

Comment: check out Jim's answer, should shed some light regarding your modulo usage with if else, maybe instead of comparing the array with modulo, compare it to the array's keys `$key % 2 == 0` something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your $chunks array is iterative (not associated) - meaning your array keys are numeric, you can grab the index like such:

```
foreach($chunks as $index => $chunk) {
    if($index % 2 == 0) {
        // stuff for even indexes
    } else {
        // stuff for odd indexes
}
```

You can also play around with `$index % 3` (for every three elements) and so on.

Comment: Just due to clarity of your answer I will mark it as correct, though for whoever else may read this be sure to read kevinabelita's comments. I don't think you can make comments marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @wr3tched no worries pal, just glad it shed some light

Comment: kevinabelita's comment below wasn't clear as to where you were to add the `$key => $chunk` snippet - plus, I think I missed his comment while I was writing my answer, otherwise I would have referenced it.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over `$chunks` inside your loop the current item is `$chunk`. However you're using `$chunks`.

So things like:

```
echo "<img src='".$chunks[0]."' alt='gallery1'/>";
```

Should probably be:

```
echo "<img src='".$chunk[0]."' alt='gallery1'/>";
```

You do something similar in the if statement:

```
$chunks % 2 == 0
```

Also note that since `$chunk` is an array you can't do `$chunk % 2`, Try `count($chunk) % 2` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the note about iterating over $chunks rather than $chunk. Also the count($chunk) will only output the number in the $chunk so in this case 3.

Comment: @wr3tched Ah, sorry. I misunderstood. I thought it was based on the entries in a chunk. I'll defer to the answer by jsickles.

Comment: Not a problem at all, I appreciate the quick help!!

Answer (score 0):

To alternate between your two design, you can't do `$chunks % 2 == 0`.
Instead, you can initialize a `$i` variable to 0, and then iterate it each loop. It's on this `$i` you can aply the modulo.

Example :

```
$i =0;
foreach($chunks as $chunk) 
{
   print_r($chunk);
   if($i % 2 == 0){
      // Design 1
   }
   else
   {
      // design 2
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Be careful, you made a mistake, you wanted `$chunk[0]` to show the images, not `$chunks[0]`

Comment: I made sure to change this in the edit already. Thanks, give me a moment to see if the i is what I was missing, though I believe it is.

Comment: actually you really dont need another variable, and another increment, just add `$key => $chunk` then `if($key % 2 == 0)` should be enough

Comment: By "=>" I take it you mean $key == $chunk, or am I mistaken?
*edit* Nevermind in the foreach loop is what you meant. Sorry for simple question.